# Action on $G$ by inner automorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions

I wonder something about an action of a group  $A$ on a group $G$ by a automorphism;

There are many nice result related with some restrictions such as when $(|A|,|G|)=1$ , $G$ is abelian or $[G,A,A]=e$...

I wonder can we say anything when we know $A$ act on $G$ by inner automorphism i.e.for any $a\in A$ and $g\in G$ there exist an $h\in G$ s.t.  $g^a=g^h$.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing you can say, because any group $A$ has the trivial group action on $G$, and in this case $A$ acts by inner automorphisms.

The assumption that $A$ acts on $G$ by inner automorphisms just gives you some homomorphism $f: A \rightarrow \operatorname{Inn}(G)$. Without any restriction on this action or on the groups $A$ and $G$, you cannot deduce anything from this.

Comment: That is a big claim :) (you can ignore the trivial action)

Comment: My trivial observation is that we can say $(|A|,|G|) \neq 1$ in that case.

Comment: Well all you get then is that there is some nontrivial homomorphism $A \rightarrow \operatorname{Inn}(G)$. I think this is a very weak condition.. I would say there is nothing nontrivial that you can find out from this

Comment: I have found a lots of article related this problem. The problem first asked by Burnside at 1911.